# How to get a selected values from listbox in a Servlet?

Tags: jsp, servlets, listbox, httprequest

In a servlet I want to get listbox selected values rendered by a JSP:

```
<td width="50%" type="text"  size="10">
    <select name="famille">
        <% while (rst.next()) {%>
            <option value="<%=rst.getString(1)%>" selected="selected">
                <%=rst.getString(1)%>
            </option>
        <% } %>
    </select>
</td>
```

Servlet code:

```
String famille = request.getParameter("famille");
System.out.println("famille      "+famille);
```

Only the first item is printed. How do I get the rest?

Comment: Well, as your `<select>` is not marked `multiple`, it behaves [exactly as specified](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html#constructing-the-form-data-set).

Answer (score 0):

In your JSP, the HTML code needs a `multiple` attribute, as per [select multiple](https://html.com/attributes/select-multiple/):

```
<td width="50%" type="text"  size="10">
    <select name="famille" multiple> <!-- `multiple` needed here -->
        <% while (rst.next()) {%>
            <option value="<%=rst.getString(1)%>" selected="selected">
                <%=rst.getString(1)%>
            </option>
        <% } %>
    </select>
</td>
```

In your Servlet code, you need to use the multiple-parameter API call:

```
String[] famille = request.getParameterValues("famille"); // Returns an array
System.out.println("famille      " + java.util.Arrays.toString(famille));
```